# Batch Script: removing characters from every folder name in source directory

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting

In my source directory, I have a variety of different folders with a kind of version extensions at the end of the name, as in the following examples:

```
C:\pathTo\source\Component.One.3.5\...
C:\pathTo\source\Component.Two.2.4\...
```

I need a Batch Script to rename the folders removing the version numbers only, like in this example:

```
C:\pathTo\source\Component.One\...
C:\pathTo\source\Component.Two\...
```

I was thinking to remove the last four characters of the name, but I don't think that this solution will work if version extensions will be more than four characters, in the future.

Have you got other ideas to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decompose the folder name in several tokens using the `for` cycle with with the `/f` switch and with `.` as delimiter. In this way you are able to consider only the first and the second tokens to rename each folder.
Here is an example using `"Component.One.3.5"` as folder name:

> for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=." %%a in ("Component.One.3.5") do (ren
>   "%%a.%%b.%%c" "%%a.%%b")